# Firefox not admitting Ctrl+Shift+3 keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, firefox

After much agony, I thought I'd finally sorted my keyboard layout/mapping to allow me the use of `3`,`£`, *and* `#`. The latter, however, is still not working in Firefox.

I have a UK layout, and am mapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> to `#` in `.xmodmap` as:

```
keycode 12 = 3 sterling sterling numbersign
```

I actually wanted `sterling` and `numbersign` the other way around, but oddly it then doesn't work, and gives me no `#` at all, for any combination.

This works fine in the terminal, but not in Firefox. Nothing else happens (as far as I can tell) when I enter that combination though, so I'm not sure if it is overriding it specifically, or blocking all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcuts or something?

Is there any way around this?

Comment: It seems Firefox might somehow be ignoring `.xmodmap` entirely: https://superuser.com/questions/883092/xmodmap-ignored-in-firefox-revisited

Comment: This assigns `#` to AltGr+Shift+3, not to Ctrl+Shift+3. Does Alt+Shift+3 insert a `#`? Why did you expect Ctrl+Shift+3 to do this?

Comment: @Gilles Ctrl+Shift+3 works in terminal; AltGr+Shift+3 doesn't (inserts `£`, just as Shift+3). The [Arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap) suggests AltGr+Shift+3 would be the 6th column, if present.